# Application of Expander Codes

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, coding-theory, expanders

I need to give a talk about [expander codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_code) at university (I'm a student of computer science). Since they have been introduced to show a family of codes looking good when thinking of the [Shannon theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noisy-channel_coding_theorem), I wonder what real world application for expander codes exist.

As far as I know one has a real hard time when encoding but decoding is quite fast. Why aren't they used to encode write only media or similar? What is their big disadvantage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One area that you could consider is **Fault Tolerant Parallel Computation**. Expander codes and graphs could be efficiently used in them like:

[Highly fault-tolerant parallel computation](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=548474), by [Daniel A. Spielman](http://cs-www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/)

[On word-level parallelism in fault-tolerant computing](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-60922-9_17?LI=true)